# Expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this expresion:

```
s.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
```

When s start with a '?' it gives SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

how to modify the expression ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Seems hacky, what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @speti43 obviously to preceed those special characters with a backslash.

Comment: For all i've noticed transfroms: ala;bala;trala to /ala;bala;trala/ but when text starts with ? fails.

Comment: @user3545298 try this regex builder: jslab.dk/tools.regex.php

Comment: what interpreter are you using?  In Firefox 28, `"?huh".replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your expression.
I just tested it with javascript to be sure, and it had no issues even when s started with a ?

The following code simply showed an alert saying "\?testing\.123":

```
<script>
    var s = "?testing.123";
    var r = s.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
    alert(r);
</script>
```

I think you need to provide more information and try to disregard your current assumptions on what is causing the error.
It would help to know what s is when it fails. And what you're doing with it before and after.